# Ruby: string brancher

Tags: ruby, string

Is there a ruby library that (as one of its features) scans a string for some "fill in the blanks" like "I'm a [robot,monkey,programmer] and I smell funny." and produces an array of complete sentences like "I'm a robot and I smell funny." "I'm a monkey and I smell funny." "I'm a programmer and I smell funny."

Answer (score 1):

```
s = "I'm a [robot,monkey,programmer] and I smell funny." 

M = /\[.*\]/
def f x
  x[M][1..-2].split(',').map { |e| x.sub(M, e) }
end
puts f s
```

Comment: Be careful, this will break if there is more than one set of braces in the string.

Answer (score 0):

I think this requirement is too simple to be implemented by yourself.  It must be much faster to write your own than searching for the existing rubygems.